# Connection ioctl and driver operations

Tags: linux, kernel

I am trying to understand how driver operations are being called. I know the ioctl system call is used for this, but I am not understanding how one would find out the commands used to end up with a particular operation. If we look at the udl driver, some files export a operations struct. For example, in udl_fb.c, we have the following:

```
static struct fb_ops udlfb_ops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    DRM_FB_HELPER_DEFAULT_OPS,
    .fb_fillrect = drm_fb_helper_sys_fillrect,
    .fb_copyarea = drm_fb_helper_sys_copyarea,
    .fb_imageblit = drm_fb_helper_sys_imageblit,
    .fb_mmap = udl_fb_mmap,
    .fb_open = udl_fb_open,
    .fb_release = udl_fb_release,
};
```

To my knowledge, we would end up at one of those functions by using ioctl with the correct command. How would I find out which command I would need to use for which operation?

Answer (score 0):

The ioctl interface is exposed in the form of a uapi (userspace API) header. In this case, it is the part of Linux FB API include/uapi/linux/fb.h.

```
/* ioctls
   0x46 is 'F'                              */
#define FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO 0x4600
#define FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO 0x4601
#define FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO 0x4602
#define FBIOGETCMAP     0x4604
#define FBIOPUTCMAP     0x4605
#define FBIOPAN_DISPLAY     0x4606
#ifndef __KERNEL__
#define FBIO_CURSOR            _IOWR('F', 0x08, struct fb_cursor)
#endif
/* 0x4607-0x460B are defined below */
/* #define FBIOGET_MONITORSPEC  0x460C */
/* #define FBIOPUT_MONITORSPEC  0x460D */
/* #define FBIOSWITCH_MONIBIT   0x460E */
#define FBIOGET_CON2FBMAP   0x460F
#define FBIOPUT_CON2FBMAP   0x4610
#define FBIOBLANK       0x4611      /* arg: 0 or vesa level + 1 */
#define FBIOGET_VBLANK      _IOR('F', 0x12, struct fb_vblank)
#define FBIO_ALLOC              0x4613
```

These ioctls are handled by FB core driver drivers/video/fbdev/core/fbmem.c when an ioctl operation is performed on the framebuffer device. Note that it handles only certain ioctls and forwards the rest to the device specific fb_ops->fb_ioctl if it implements one.

```
static long do_fb_ioctl(struct fb_info *info, unsigned int cmd,
            unsigned long arg)
{
    struct fb_ops *fb;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo var;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo fix;
    struct fb_cmap cmap_from;
    struct fb_cmap_user cmap;
    void __user *argp = (void __user *)arg;
    long ret = 0;

    switch (cmd) {
    case FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO:
        lock_fb_info(info);
        var = info->var;
        unlock_fb_info(info);

        ret = copy_to_user(argp, &var, sizeof(var)) ? -EFAULT : 0;
        break;
    case FBIOPUT_VSCREENINFO:
        if (copy_from_user(&var, argp, sizeof(var)))
            return -EFAULT;
        console_lock();
        lock_fb_info(info);
        info->flags |= FBINFO_MISC_USEREVENT;
        ret = fb_set_var(info, &var);
        info->flags &= ~FBINFO_MISC_USEREVENT;
        unlock_fb_info(info);
        console_unlock();
        if (!ret && copy_to_user(argp, &var, sizeof(var)))
            ret = -EFAULT;
        break;
    case FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO:
        lock_fb_info(info);
        fix = info->fix;
        if (info->flags & FBINFO_HIDE_SMEM_START)
            fix.smem_start = 0;
        unlock_fb_info(info);

        ret = copy_to_user(argp, &fix, sizeof(fix)) ? -EFAULT : 0;
        break;
    case FBIOPUTCMAP:
        if (copy_from_user(&cmap, argp, sizeof(cmap)))
            return -EFAULT;
        ret = fb_set_user_cmap(&cmap, info);
        break;
    case FBIOGETCMAP:
        if (copy_from_user(&cmap, argp, sizeof(cmap)))
            return -EFAULT;
        lock_fb_info(info);
        cmap_from = info->cmap;
        unlock_fb_info(info);
        ret = fb_cmap_to_user(&cmap_from, &cmap);
        break;
    case FBIOPAN_DISPLAY:
        if (copy_from_user(&var, argp, sizeof(var)))
            return -EFAULT;
        console_lock();
        lock_fb_info(info);
        ret = fb_pan_display(info, &var);
        unlock_fb_info(info);
        console_unlock();
        if (ret == 0 && copy_to_user(argp, &var, sizeof(var)))
            return -EFAULT;
        break;
    case FBIO_CURSOR:
        ret = -EINVAL;
        break;
    case FBIOGET_CON2FBMAP:
        ret = fbcon_get_con2fb_map_ioctl(argp);
        break;
    case FBIOPUT_CON2FBMAP:
        ret = fbcon_set_con2fb_map_ioctl(argp);
        break;
    case FBIOBLANK:
        console_lock();
        lock_fb_info(info);
        ret = fb_blank(info, arg);
        /* might again call into fb_blank */
        fbcon_fb_blanked(info, arg);
        unlock_fb_info(info);
        console_unlock();
        break;
    default:
        lock_fb_info(info);
        fb = info->fbops;
        if (fb->fb_ioctl)
            ret = fb->fb_ioctl(info, cmd, arg);
        else
            ret = -ENOTTY;
        unlock_fb_info(info);
    }
    return ret;
}

static long fb_ioctl(struct file *file, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    struct fb_info *info = file_fb_info(file);

    if (!info)
        return -ENODEV;
    return do_fb_ioctl(info, cmd, arg);
}
```

From your code, it is using some default fb ops DRM_FB_HELPER_DEFAULT_OPS defined in include/drm/drm_fb_helper.h.

```
 */
#define DRM_FB_HELPER_DEFAULT_OPS \
    .fb_check_var   = drm_fb_helper_check_var, \
    .fb_set_par = drm_fb_helper_set_par, \
    .fb_setcmap = drm_fb_helper_setcmap, \
    .fb_blank   = drm_fb_helper_blank, \
    .fb_pan_display = drm_fb_helper_pan_display, \
    .fb_debug_enter = drm_fb_helper_debug_enter, \
    .fb_debug_leave = drm_fb_helper_debug_leave, \
    .fb_ioctl   = drm_fb_helper_ioctl
```

and in drivers/gpu/drm/drm_fb_helper.c

```
int drm_fb_helper_ioctl(struct fb_info *info, unsigned int cmd,
            unsigned long arg)
{
    struct drm_fb_helper *fb_helper = info->par;
    struct drm_device *dev = fb_helper->dev;
    struct drm_crtc *crtc;
    int ret = 0;

    mutex_lock(&fb_helper->lock);
    if (!drm_master_internal_acquire(dev)) {
        ret = -EBUSY;
        goto unlock;
    }

    switch (cmd) {
    case FBIO_WAITFORVSYNC:
        /*
         * Only consider the first CRTC.
         *
         * This ioctl is supposed to take the CRTC number as
         * an argument, but in fbdev times, what that number
         * was supposed to be was quite unclear, different
         * drivers were passing that argument differently
         * (some by reference, some by value), and most of the
         * userspace applications were just hardcoding 0 as an
         * argument.
         *
         * The first CRTC should be the integrated panel on
         * most drivers, so this is the best choice we can
         * make. If we're not smart enough here, one should
         * just consider switch the userspace to KMS.
         */
        crtc = fb_helper->client.modesets[0].crtc;

        /*
         * Only wait for a vblank event if the CRTC is
         * enabled, otherwise just don't do anythintg,
         * not even report an error.
         */
        ret = drm_crtc_vblank_get(crtc);
        if (!ret) {
            drm_crtc_wait_one_vblank(crtc);
            drm_crtc_vblank_put(crtc);
        }

        ret = 0;
        break;
    default:
        ret = -ENOTTY;
    }

    drm_master_internal_release(dev);
unlock:
    mutex_unlock(&fb_helper->lock);
    return ret;
}
EXPORT_SYMBOL(drm_fb_helper_ioctl);
```

The rest of the device fb_ops are there to be called directly from the kernel space code working on framebuffer device.